# What command to use to edit a package.xml file in ROS Hydro?

Tags: ros, package.xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anybody tell which command to use to edit a package.xml file in ROS Hydro? Using the command cat package.xml, I can view the package.xml file but I am unable to edit the file. Can anybody help please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190594/what-command-to-use-to-edit-a-package.xml-file-in-ros-hydro?/) by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2014-08-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bhargav](https://answers.ros.org/users/5029/bhargav/) on 2014-08-19**:
Which OS are you using? If its ubuntu then use a text editor with sudo command prefixed to it.

sudo gedit .....yourfilename....

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-08-19**:
Do NOT use sudo to edit package.xml files. It is unnecessary and will mess up permissions.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-08-19**:
Please choose a meaningful title that shortly states what the question is about.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-08-20**:
gedit package.xml

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to all. gedit is working for me now.

---

Originally posted by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) with karma: 151 on 2014-08-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-20**:
Try to carefully read and follow the tutorial before making something else. And do not change the package.xml, before being sure to know what you are doing

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-08-20**:
Please accept an answer using the checkbox at the left of each answer so others know that this question has been solved in the future.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
vi package.xml
```

vi or vim works. vim is just extension to vi.

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2014-08-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-08-19**:
wait are you trying to edit a system ros package.xml file? If so, it is highly recommended you do not do so, unless you REALLY, REALLY, know what your doing.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any text editor will work. Ubuntu comes with gedit and nano preinstalled.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-08-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3